# C# Create, check, loop through objects

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

such a weird situation appears in front of me. Here is the thing.
If I would do this in PHP or some other programming language it would be easy but in C# I dont know how can I achieve this.

Brief description of my problem:

1. I have a UserForm in C# with combobox. In this combobox I have as many items as there are in the database -> so its dynamically filled on the start of the application
2. Each item should represent single UserForm. So here is the problem, if user choses item and clicks on button check should be fired if that userform has been created, if its not, then a new (object ?) userform must be created. Normally I would delete and recreate new form everytime user choses new option but I want to keep those Userforms and create them once and then only hide them or show them, so textinputs etc. remain filled while application will run (but I dont thing that creating 15-20 UserForms at the start of the app is okay in terms of performance).

So what I was thinking of doing and what I tried:

1. I wanted to use the name of chosen item from the combobox and use it as a Object (UserForm) name. (also perform check if it already exists before creating) -> apparently this is not possible in C# to use string variable as object name
2. I googled about Dictionaries, but can I store there whole UserForms ?
3. Also I was thinking of creating all 15-20 Userforms at the beginning and then looping through them and show them or hide them.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a caching problem. You want to cache the forms.

So first you need a container for the cache, e.g.

```
var cache = new List<UserForm>();
```

Then, when a form is needed, you need a special method to search the cache and add to it if needed. Because there is more than one type of form, you'll want to use generics here:

```
T GetOrCreateForm<T> where T: UserForm, new()
{
    UserForm f = cache.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();  //Search cache
    if (f == default(T))                              //If not found,
    {
        f = new T();                                  //Create it anew
        cache.Add(f);                                 //and add it to the cache
    }
    return f;                                         //return the form we just created/retrieved
}
```

You would then call this method, passing the type of the form desired:

```
var form1 = GetOrCreateForm<Form1>();
form1.Show();
```

The above assumes there is one type of form (one class) for each row in the list. If you actually have a common form class, but they are distinguished by something else (e.g. maybe each form has a unique `Name` property that is set at run time) then you'd need a dictionary to tell the forms apart:

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string, UserForm>();

UserForm GetOrCreateForm(string name)
{
    UserForm f;
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(name, out f))
    {
        f = new UserForm { Name = name };
        cache.Add(name, f); 
    }
    return f;         
}


var myForm = GetOrCreateForm("SomeUniqueName");
myForm.Show();
```

Comment: I personally think a dictionary would be better suited. What if more than one item shares the same type of form?

Comment: Thank you John Wu, I will give it a try tomorrow, but it looks very good for what I need.
@Juan what do you mean by ,,same type" ?

Comment: @Juan, edited to accommodate one form/multiple instances, assuming we can tell them apart by some property such as `Name`.

Comment: Awesome, @JohnWu. I think whatever he stores in the combo box will probably suffice as a key.

Comment: @ŠtevkoMarcin: I was thinking of a case where you have more than one item in the combo box that uses the same type of form. For instance, suppose you have `Cat` and `Dog` in the combo box and you use a form of type `Animal` to edit these types. In such case, using a function that gets you the form by type would not work because it would return a single instance for both. A dictionary on the other hand uses a key which by definition is unique. @JhonWu updated his answer with an alternate method for such cases.

Comment: @Juan yes, now I understand, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWu, I used the first approach but I still struggle with selecting one of the prepared Forms -> I mean this:

var settings_for_this_platform = platform_options.Text;
var myForm = GetOrCreateForm<settings_for_this_platform >(); // it doesnt work ... because I want to use value in this variable as name of Form